# What SF character, a lab director, didn't take credit for combining his subordinates' results?

Tags: story-identification, e-e-doc-smith

I remember a character who, upon being appointed to be director of a research lab, spent his first weeks reading his workers' reports.  He then called in a few to his office and told them that if they combined their discoveries they would have a useful result.  They were disappointed because they expected him to take credit for the result, but he did not.  Instead he earned their loyalty.
I thought this was a character in the Lensman series but I checked my copy of Triplanetary and it isn't there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[First Lensman, chapter 16](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/49525)

George Olmstead (cousin of the First Lensman) is undercover (sort of - the bad guys know who he is but don't think he's loyal to his cousin) at the thionite processing plant.

> "Morning, boys. I'm not up on the fundamental theory of any one of these three reports, but if you combine this, and this, and this," indicating heavily-penciled sections of the three documents, "would you, or would you not, be able to work out a process that would do away with about three-quarters of the final purification and separation processes?"
>
> They did not know. It had not been the business of any one of them, or of all them collectively, to find out.
>
> "I'm making it your business as of now. Drop whatever you're doing, put your heads together, and find out. Theory first, then a small-scale laboratory experiment. Then come back here on the double."
>
> "Yes, sir," and in a few days they were back.
>
> "Does it work?"
>
> "In theory it should, sir, and on a laboratory scale it does." The three young men were, if possible, even stiffer than before. It was not the first time, nor would it be the last, that a Director of Research would seize credit for work which he was not capable of doing.
>
> "Good. Miss Reed, get me Rand ... Rand? Olmstead. Three of my boys have just hatched out something that may be worth quite a few million credits a year to us.... Me? Hell, no! Talk to them. I can't understand any one of the three parts of it, to say nothing of inventing it. I want you to give 'em a class AAA priority on the pilot plant, as of right now. If they can develop it, and I'm betting they can, I'm going to put their pictures in the Northport News and give 'em a couple of thousand credits apiece and a couple of weeks vacation to spend it in.... Yeah, I'll send 'em in." He turned to the flabbergasted three. "Take your dope in to Rand--now. Show him what you've got; then tear into that pilot plant."

Comment: For anyone who uses these story-identification requests like I do, as a source of ideas for books to read, I should point out that this is the worst one in the series. It's a prequel (or midquel or something - fitting between the original series and the first prequel (Triplanetary) which itself was a standalone story revamped to function as a prequel). Start with the "third" book (Galactic Patrol) and work forward from there to avoid disappointment!

Comment: I disagree... reading them in the order the books were published in is fine.  Based on the original serialization dates in Wikipedia, Triplanetary _did_ come first, then Galactic Patrol, then the rest, and then First Lensman is - as you say - a fill-in.  But even if it's a bit slower than the later books, it's still a good read.

Comment: Ward:  No, Wumbley is right, and _Triplanetary_ was not originally part of the Lensman series, and _First Lensman_ was written last of all.  The Arisians in it are inconsistent with the original versions, who actually made sense and were far from omniscient.  (Why would omniscient beings have needed to create _four_ competing bloodlines to use only one?)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Lensman_series#Differences_between_the_original_and_ret-con_versions_of_the_series